# Map a list of list to TPU tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, tpu

I have this code to deconstruct a list of list to different tensors.

```
token_a_index, token_b_index, isNext, input_ids, segment_ids, masked_tokens, masked_pos = map(torch.LongTensor, zip(*batch))
```

If I want to create these tensors on gpu, I can use below code:

```
token_a_index, token_b_index, isNext, input_ids, segment_ids, masked_tokens, masked_pos = map(torch.cuda.LongTensor, zip(*batch))
```

But now I want to create all these on TPU, what should I do? Is there anything like below?

```
token_a_index, token_b_index, isNext, input_ids, segment_ids, masked_tokens, masked_pos = map(torch.xla.LongTensor, zip(*batch))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xla device following the guide [here](https://pytorch.org/xla/release/1.12/index.html).

You can select the device and pass it to your function like this:

```
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
device = xm.xla_device()
token_a_index, token_b_index, isNext, input_ids, segment_ids, masked_tokens, masked_pos = map(lambda x: torch.Tensor(x).to(device).long(), zip(*batch))
```

You can even parametrize the device variable, `torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")` can be used to select between `cuda` and `cpu`.